# jquery - reveal answer in definition list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an FAQ page that looks like the markup shown below

When the page loads I'd like to reveal the answer that corresponds to the bookmark in the URL

The url will be of the form www.mydomain.com/page#q1

I am trying to do it like this but it wont't work - any ideas how to fix it?

```
console.log($(hash).length)
```

does have a length of 1 so it is selecting a dom element

And I have used the same functionality to reveal it on click further down the script - and tht works OK

```
$(function () {

        var hash = window.location.hash;
        //hash = hash.replace('#', '');
        console.log('hash:' + hash);
        console.log($(hash).length);

        $(hash)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find("dd.answer")
            .slideToggle();

        $("dd.answer")
                .hide();

        $("dt.question")
                .click(function () {
                    $(this)
                        .parent()
                        .find("dd.answer")
                        .slideToggle();
                });
    });

<dl>
    <dt class="question">
        <a id="q1"></a>
        Question 1
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">
        Answer 1
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt class="question">
        <a id="q2"></a>
        Question 2
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">
        Answer 2
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt class="question">
        <a id="q3"></a>
        Question 3
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">
        Answer 3
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: You are doing `.find("dd.answer").slideToggle()` and then you hide all of them `$("dd.answer").hide();`. Invert the statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were hiding the dds after revealing using the hash.

try this instead:

```
<html>

    <head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        var hash = window.location.hash;
        //hash = hash.replace('#', '');
        console.log('hash:' + hash);
        console.log($(hash).length);

        $('dd').hide();

        $(hash).parents('dl').find('dd').slideToggle()

        $("dt.question")
                .click(function () {
            $(this)
                        .parent()
                        .find("dd.answer")
                        .slideToggle();
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>

<dl>
    <dt class="question">
        <a id="q1"></a>
        Question 1
    <dd class="answer" >
        Answer 1
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt class="question">
        <a id="q2"></a>
        Question 2
    <dd class="answer" >
        Answer 2
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt class="question">
        <a id="q3"></a>
        Question 3
    <dd class="answer" >
        Answer 3
    </dd>
</dl>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: haha...oh dear, do I feel stupid. Gonna put that one down to it being Monday. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var hash = "#" + window.location.hash;
```

As the original `#` in the URL is removed as it is an indicator of the hash start.
JQuery expects an ID selector to start with a `#` so you have to add it yourself.